# Is the deep web halal?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, internet

I know someone who is muslim and has taken a recent interest in the dark web.  It is really concerning me because he is talking about things which seem haram.

Is using the deep web halal?

Comment: Depends on what one does using it. Pornography and purchase of stolen items etc. is obviously haram.

Answer (score -1):

If your friend is doing research on the deep web to see how it is being used for the purposes of social policy, then this is obviously not haram but halal.

However, if your friend is using the deep web in order to access things which, given what you say, is haram - say drugs, porn or stolen goods - then this is as haram as it would be in real life.